Firebird 5.0.1 closes applications and requires reboot
In our application we use Firebird as a database. An install-launcher program (a simple win32 program) performs a scripted installation of Firebird, then of the main application, by calling both installers one after the other with command line options.
This always worked with FB2.x - 4.0.5.
The new 5.0.1 installer suddenly misbehaves:
When running the Firebird5.0.1 64bit installer on a fresh Win10 machine, in the same moment when the installer states its installing MSVC 32-bit runtime libraries, it closes the our install launcher that would install (as a next step) the main application.
It also requires a complete reboot after installation, that it never did before.
The Install launcher is also closed if the FB-installer is launched manually (without parameters) - but only if the install launcher is from a network share and the 32-app was also started from that network share.
The Message "To complete the installation of Firebird, Setup must restart your computer. Would you like to restart now?" shows up in either case.
Following Mark Rotteveels hint I tried running the installer with "/NORESTART /Silent /NOGDS32" - then the reboot-question does not show, but the service is also not started. Als it can be started manually, so there seems to be no reason no to do that.
This breaks the automatic installation.
Is there a trick to get that working, or do I have to revert to an older version of Firebird to implement an application installation that runs through in one go?

After some more checking:
If I install the MSVC installer from https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170

If I install the X86 installer, then the launcher application is not closed by the FB installer
If I install the X64 installer, then the FB-installer can launch the FB service after installation.

Both MS installers don't require a system reboot.
Could it be, that the MSVC installation is not done properly by the FB installer?

In any case, this doesn't sound like a suitable question for Stack Overflow. Consider asking on firebird-support, or reporting a bug on the Firebird GitHub.

That said, AFAIK, a reboot can be required if it needed to install a newer version of the MSVC libraries than currently installed, which can definitely happen on a fresh install of Windows 10.

BTW, you haven't provided the installer commands you use, but are you passing /NORESTART?

Hey Mark, thanks for the hints. I corrected the question and answered your parameter-question directly in the question. In previous versions of FB the MSVC was updated w/o closing running applications - even on stone old plain Win7 systems. And the fact, that the application is only closed when it was started from a network drive "smells" like that's not really related to the MSCV version.

Posted on Github: https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/issues/8326
